# How does the unusual rule for dissolving Swedish Parliament come about?

Tags: constitution, parliament, sweden

Sweden - unlike other European countries - has a Parliament that serves **fixed** 4-year term.

The Government can order extra elections to take place in between the 4-year term, but the extra elections do not change the fixed timetable of regular elections.

For instance, if an extra election takes place 2 years into the 4-year term, the election that comes after will be scheduled to take place 2 years later as planned.

I'm curious what caused this arrangement during Sweden's constitution drafting process? Is this a compromise between different parties? What is the central disagreement that led to this compromise?

Comment: What research have you already done and what have you found?  Why do you assume that there was a disagreement?

Comment: @phoog I can't find any record regarding this aspect of Sweden's constitution drafting process. But seeing that this manner of dissolution is not the norm in European politics, I assume it must be a product of some negotiation among drafting parties. Otherwise why add this extra layer of complexity when they can just renew the four-year term like all of its neighbours?

Comment: I don't know why things are like that in Sweden specifically but I can offer a possible explanation.  This is likely to stop a government from calling an election at whatever point in the second half of their term that they think they are most likely to win and reset the clock.  You know the downside of your voter pleasing tax cuts is about to hit in the next few months?  Call an election now and hope the voters have forgotten in four years.  The Swedish system seems like an interesting compromise between the two prevalent systems (fixed term and freely decided by the government).

Comment: You might want to look in to the UK's Fixed Term Parliaments Act which was intended to prevent the government from fishing for the optimal time to reset the clock albeit in a different way to Sweden.

Comment: @phoog Another reason that I suspect it is a result of political compromise is that Sweden's dissolution rule heavily constrains the Government's power to use snap election as a means to extend its term by hopping on good timing. This suggests that whoever holds parliamentary majority at the time of drafting process probably agreed to this concession in exchange for other things.

Comment: @EricNolan: the FTPA was widely considered a failure, and has now been repealed.

Comment: See https://www.libdemvoice.org/swedishstyle-fixed-term-parliaments-68605.html which promotes the swedish model

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sweden adopted a new basic law about the operation of the state in the
1970's called [Regeringsformen
(1974:152)](https://www.riksdagen.se/sv/dokument-lagar/dokument/svensk-forfattningssamling/kungorelse-1974152-om-beslutad-ny-regeringsform_sfs-1974-152)
(regeringsform ~= form of government - can't really be
translated). Among the major changes were making the bicameral
parliament unicameral. 3 kap. §11 reads:

> Regeringen får besluta om extra val till riksdagen mellan ordinarie
> val. Extra val ska hållas inom tre månader efter beslutet.  Efter
> val till riksdagen får regeringen inte besluta om extra val förrän
> tre månader har gått från den nyvalda riksdagens första
> sammanträde. Regeringen får inte heller besluta om extra val under
> den tid då dess ledamöter, efter det att samtliga har entledigats,
> uppehåller sina befattningar till dess en ny regering ska tillträda.

These sentences define what the terms "ordinarie val" (ordinary
election) and "extra val" (extra election) means and they imply fixed
terms.

In the 1960's two investigations were launched to investigate how to
modernise Sweden's regeringsform. At that time many considered it to
be obsolete since it was in large parts based on the regeringsform
adopted in 1809. The first of these was Författningsutredningen and
the other Grundlagsberedningen. From the former's interim report [SOU
1963:17](https://lagen.nu/sou/1963:17#sid1-img):

> Enligt nuvarande bestämmelser börjar icke en ny valperiod löpa efter
> nyvalsförordnande och riksdagsupplösning utan valet gäller endast
> den återstående delen av valperioden. En ändring av dessa regler,
> som är i det närmaste unika för vårt land, har vid några tillfällen
> under 1930-talet föreslagits men avvisats av riksdagen,
> bl. a. under hänvisning till att en utsträckt användning av
> upplösningsinstitutet över huvud icke var önskvärd och till att
> rörliga valperioder skulle rubba den fasta växlingen mellan
> kommunal- och riksdagsval. Givet är att urtima val, såsom uttryck
> för en allvarlig konflikt mellan regering och riksdag, icke i och
> för sig är eftersträvansvärda. Föreligger emellertid den situationen
> att en samverkan mellan regering och riksdag i väsentliga frågor ej
> kan åstadkommas, kräver hänsynen till parlamentarismens och därmed
> också folkstyrelsens funktionsduglighet att denna konflikt
> undanröjes. Med den omfattning statsverksamheten har i våra dagar är
> det utomordentligt angeläget att statsmakternas handlingskraft
> bevaras. Ett urtima val kan medföra en lösning av en föreliggande
> konfliktsituation och således vara ett effektivt hjälpmedel i
> folkstyrelsens tjänst. Reglerna om urtima val bör därför ej vara så
> utformade att de i praktiken försvårar institutets utnyttjande. Ur
> denna synpunkt vore rörliga valperioder att föredraga.
>
> Till förmån för fasta valperioder talar främst hänsynen till de
> kommunala valen. Även om dessa val enligt det föreslagna
> enkammarsystemet kommer att mista sin direkta betydelse för
> riksdagens sammansättning, kommer givetvis de politiska partierna
> att även i fortsättningen ha all anledning att ägna de kommunala
> valen stort intresse. Man får då liksom hittills två stora
> valrörelser och det är naturligt, både ur medborgarnas och
> partiorganisationernas synpunkt, med en fast växling mellan dessa
> val. Med rörliga valperioder kan riksdagsval och kommunala val
> t. ex. komma att sammanfalla eller inträffa med endast ett års
> mellanrum, varefter skulle följa i det första fallet fyra, i det
> andra fallet tre år utan allmänna val. Ej heller synes det önskvärt,
> att man från ett system med fasta valperioder skulle gå över till
> dess motsats, den i Storbritannien tillämpade ordningen enligt
> vilken regeringen normalt söker välja den tidpunkt för valet, före
> den femåriga valperiodens utgång, som från regeringens synpunkt ter
> sig som den mest lämpliga. En sådan praxis ger regeringen en favör i
> förhållande till oppositionen — en favör förstärkt genom modern
> opinionsmätningsteknik — som knappast förefaller motiverad.

Translating this text would be nigh impossible so I won't try. It says
that the current rules mandates fixed terms and that those rules are
almost unique for Sweden. It goes on to claim that changes to those
rules were proposed a few times in the 1930's, but rejected by the
parliament because they could cause more instability. However, the
text also emphasizes that the ability of the government to call for
extra elections is important to resolve serious parliamentary
conflicts or deadlocks.

Then the text argues that fixed terms are good because municipal
elections happens two years after national elections. This cycle would
be disturbed if terms were not fixed and in the worst case there would
be no elections for four consecutive years. Ostensibly, that would be
bad for democracy. Now that is the norm since the 1974 regeringsform
made municipal elections coincide with national elections and the term
length was increased to four years in the 1990's, so go
figure. Finally, it argues that Great Britain is a deterring example;
that the ability of the government to set the election date favors it
in relation to the opposition - especially so when considering modern
polling methods.

So it seems to me that Sweden has had fixed terms ever since the
bicameral parliament was [created in
1866](https://sv.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representationsreformen_i_Sverige)
and that this order has never been seriously challenged.

Comment: as a German I would have assumed "regeringsform" means something like "government process", which seems to be exactly what it is.

Comment: Perhaps. I dont know enough about the topic to dare to translate these terms. There may be some legal nuances that makes word-for-word translations misleading.